# One class - few Xibs

Tags: ios, xib, viewcontroller

I want to create a specific `xib` for every screen size, but with one `UIViewController`.

How can I connect few xibs to one class?

Comment: I think it's important to ask why you might need to do this? It's likely that your problems could be solved with a single xib and autolayout/size classes. Have you looked into autolayout?

Comment: @PatrickGoley I did, I have a complicated view and it's almost impossible to adjust it with constraints, i've tried for hours and I think the best way will be to add a specific xib for every size

Comment: Even still, it might be easier to just adjust some constraints of a single xib in code rather than duplicating the whole layout. You have to realize you're creating a maintenance nightmare by repeating your UI work in 4+ xib files. You'll hate yourself when changes or updates are needed.

Comment: did u use size classes?

Comment: @PatrickGoley I need to place a label under a shape that is inside an image (a background image with that shape inside the PNG file), I need it to be exactly 5px under that shape. It's impossible with constraints

Comment: @FS.O5 I see your challenge there. My point is that it'd be better to have one xib with a an outlet to the label's constraint and adjust the constraint on a per device basis (pre-measure and hardcode values). This will be MUCH easier than creating and maintaining a handful of copied xibs forever.

Comment: @PatrickGoley Oh I see what's you point. I'll try that. thanks!

Comment: Could you please post a mockup picture of what you were trying to achieve? It doesn't really make sense creating multiple xibs for different screen sizes unless the layouts are totally different and is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

*MyClass is your `UIViewController`*

**1. Create different `xib`s**

```
myclass_iphone4
myclass_iphone5
myclass_iphone6
```

**2. Each `xib` will have as file's owner MyClass to link the outlets**

**3. Load MyClass dynamically:**

```
let deviceSize = //iphone4, iphone5, ....
let viewcontroller = MyClass(nibName: "myclass_\(deviceSize)", bundle: nil)
```

*Let me know in the comments if it could be ok for you.*

Comment: MyClass should be `UIViewController`. And how can I share properties between those xibs and class?

Comment: What about the shared properties?

Comment: @FS.O5 you can link your outlet using the file's owner